# Wpf webbrowser + ftp server

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, webbrowser-control

**Problem:** 
I have wpf webbrowser controll and FTP server.
In code:

```
wpfWebbrowserControll.Soure = new Uri (ftpUri)
```

Then in `wpfWebbrowserControll` shown all FTP server content 
But then - when i click on a folder, windows explorer opens new window with folders content (its a problem)

I need do all only in my controll!

Ps: when `wpfWebbrowserControll.Soure = new Uri("C:\\")` - all work like i want
thanks

Comment: If you solve your problem, can you answer your own question. This will maybe help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When WebBrowser loads ftp page it actually shows you COM object which implements [IShellFolderViewDual3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) COM interface, so the idea is to intercept DefaultVerb and update WebBrowser source.

```
private void browser_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e) {
    dynamic document = this.browser.Document;

    document.DefaultVerbInvoked += new Func<bool>(() => {
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
            if ((int) document.SelectedItems.Count > 0) {
                var selectedItem = document.SelectedItems.Item(0);
                this.browser.Source = new Uri((string) selectedItem.Path);
            }
        }));
        return false;
    });
}

<WebBrowser
   x:Name="browser"
   LoadCompleted="browser_LoadCompleted"
   Source="ftp://ftp.drweb.com/pub/drweb/" />
```