# WebBrowser control open FTP Server folder

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to open a FTP server in my WebBrowser control, which works fine but when I double-click a folder, it opens it in Windows Explorer and not in my WebBrowser, which is what I want.

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710679/wpf-webbrowser-ftp-server) question but the answer only works on WPF, not on WinForms, which is what I use.

Comment: I can't test it, but maybe it's your folder or browser default settings. [Maybe this related question will help.](https://superuser.com/questions/1099494/windows-10-ftp-folder-keeps-opening-in-browser-how-do-i-change-it)